# First Order Logic: Skolemization

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Given: $\,\,\,\forall w\,\, \exists x\,\, \forall y\,\, \exists z\,\,  P(w, x, y, z).$

Is this the correct representation after skolemization:
$$\forall w\,\, \forall y\,\,\,\, P(w, f(w), y, f(w, y))\,\,?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the Skolem functions have to be distinguished from each other, but you've used "$f$" twice. (This may have just been a typo of course.)

However, that's the only issue: once we rename the second "$f$," we get a correct Skolemization, e.g. $$\forall w\forall y P(w,f(w),y,g(w,y)).$$

In particular, you've *correctly* noted that the Skolem function corresponding to the second existentially-bound variable (in this case "$z$") has to take as inputs *both* $w$ and $y$. This is one of the more common stumbling blocks, so it's good that you've done it correctly here.

Comment: Thanks @Noah Schweber!